# Abap : convert svg to png

Tags: javascript, svg, png, abap

I have an svg file and I want to convert it to image png, I am searching any class that do this in ABAP but I could not find any results.
I tried to do this with Javascript then execute it from ABAP but my code in JS should be without DOM implementation or browser functionalities to be able to run it from ABAP.

Answer (score 2):

SVG is - as its name implies - a vector graphics format while PNG is a raster graphics format. Converting vector graphics to raster graphics requires all kinds of "interesting" capabilities that ABAP isn't really suitable for, for instance rendering text in (almost) any font with various attributes and modifiers into a bitmap. I would be surprised if a pure ABAP solution existed at all. It should be possible from a technical point of view, but as you might imagine, it'd be an enormous task.

That being said, you might want to try to use the IMGCONV part of the [Internet Graphics Service](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/17/86c039c7811f11e10000000a114084/content.htm?frameset=/en/46/8cafa3e6390e9ce10000000a155369/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/6a/44b2420e71c511e10000000a1550b0/plain.htm&node_id=316&show_children=false). I'm not sure whether it support SVG, but you might want to check out the classes `CL_IGS_*`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing this with a GUI attached running windows. If that's an option. The back-end server-side Java interpreter does lack a DOM, yes. But perhaps you can find a library that can do this in Java without a DOM? Should be easier than doing the bit manipulations required in ABAP.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot convert an SVG into a PNG or JPEG in abap.
First of all you have to download the SVG file and open it in Paint, if you use win. Then save it as bitmap in 256 color. After that you can convert it into png files. (why? If you load the file without converting it to 256-color bitmaps, SAP may not interpret the colors well. Withe can became gray and gray can became blu)
Advice: if you want to use the image in smartforms or adobeforms or sapscritp, best way is to upload it in bitmap in se78 transaction and call it in you printouts or alv header